# Magento 2.0.1 problem with my custom theme

Tags: magento2, php, layout, theme, cms

I am using Magento 2.0.1 and I created a custom theme in `app\design\frontend\MyTheme`

Now, I am setting my custom theme in back end and I created following folders and files

```
\web

\media

\etc 

registration.php

theme.xml
```

After this, I pasted the folders of **Magento_Module**

from `\vendor\magento\theme-blank` of Magento_Module to `app\design\frontend\mytheme`.

My structure is `app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name.`

In this folder I have three folders: `\etc \media \web` and other two files `registration.php and theme.xml.`

The problem is that I can not understand why the files phtml template Magento can not read them from path of my theme. Magento reads files phtml of the site only in this path `\vendor\magento\magento_module.`

Why this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you able to choose your theme from the admin panel? Does it show up in the list of themes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am reading your question correctly, you have your files under `app/design/frontend/Theme`. The correct structure is `app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/theme_name`.

Comment: My structure is app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name. In this folder i have three folders: \etc \media \web and other two files registration.php and theme.xml. The problem is that I can not understand why the files phtml template Magento not read them from my path of my theme. Magento reads files phtml of the site only in this path \vendor\magento\magento_module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is theme fallback mechanism. For some reasons if magento can't find files to render it will fallback to parent code. If still not found it will back to base core

```
/**
 * Find asset file via fallback mechanism
 *
 * @param LocalInterface $asset
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\FallbackContext $context
 * @return bool|string
 */
private function findFileThroughFallback(
    LocalInterface $asset,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\FallbackContext $context
) {
    $themeModel = $this->themeList->getThemeByFullPath($context->getAreaCode() . '/' . $context->getThemePath());
    $sourceFile = $this->fallback->getFile(
        $context->getAreaCode(),
        $themeModel,
        $context->getLocale(),
        $asset->getFilePath(),
        $asset->getModule()
    );
    return $sourceFile;
}
```